# user doesn't stay logged in - laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, web-development-server

I'm facing i problem where the user on the website after logging in it redirect him to the home page and everything works fine, but when the user goes to any other page he is no longer logged in and i don't know whats the problem.

sorry in new to this so if there is anything you need more just tell me

I'm using:
laravel: 5.7 
php : 7.1.3

**the routes:**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;



Route::get('/','PagesController@index');

Route::get('/login','PagesController@login');
Route::post('/login','PagesController@validateLogin');

Route::post('/signup','PagesController@insert');
Route::get('/signup','PagesController@signup');


Route::get('/postRequest','PagesController@postRequest');
Route::post('/postRequest','PagesController@postuser');

Route::get('/session','PagesController@usession');
```

**The session config file:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('PHP', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

**the PageController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use database\migrations;
use DB;
use Validator;
use App\users;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
 //Abdulmalik
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        return view('index');
    }
    public function postRequest() {

        return view('postRequest');
    }
    public function postuser() {
        $user1 = new users();
    $email = request('reqName');
    $pass = request('reqDesc');
    $fn = request('category');
    $ln = request('skills');
$user1->email =$email;
$user1->password=$pass;
$user1->firstName=$fn;
$user1->lastName=$ln;

$user1->save();

        return view('postRequest');
    }
    public function login() {
        return view('login');
    }
    public function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
         if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>  request('email'), 'password' =>  request('password')])) {
             // Success
            // $message = "successfully login ";
            // echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

             //$value = $request->session()->all();//Session::get('laravel_session');
             //Session::put('userId', $value);
             //$request->session()->keep(['laravel_session']);
             //echo $value;
             return view('index');



         } else {
             return "something happened"/*redirect()->back()*/;
         };
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function signup() {
        return view('signup');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    public function insert(){
        $errors="";
        $firstName = request('Fname');
        $lastName = request('Lname');
        $pass = request('password');
        $em = request('email');
        $conpass = request('conPassword');
        $validation = Validator::make(
            [ //parameters
                'firstName' => request('Fname'),
                'lastName' => request('Lname'),
                'password' => request('password'),
                'email' => request('email'),
                'password_confirmation' => request('conPassword'),
            ], //rule
            [
                'firstName' => ['required','string','max:255' ],
                'lastName' => ['required','string','max:255' ],
                'password' => ['required','string','min:6','confirmed' ],
                'password_confirmation' => [],
                'email' => ['required', 'email','unique:users'],
            ],//error messages
            ['firstName.required' =>"الرجاء إدخال الاسم الأول *",
                'lastName.required' =>"الرجاء إدخال اسم العائلة *",
                'password.required' =>"الرجاء إدخال كلمة المرور *",
                'password.min' =>"كلمة المرور يجب ان تتكون من ستة خانات على الأقل *",
                'password.confirmed' =>"كلمة المرور يجب ان تتطابق *",
                'email.required' =>"الرجاء إدخال البريد الالكتروني *",
                'email.unique' =>"البريد الالكتروني مسجل مسبقا *ً",
                'email.email' =>"البريد الالكتروني يجب ان يكون بالصيغة الصحيحة *ً",

            ]
        );

        if ( $validation->fails() ) {
            $errors = $validation->messages();
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
        }
        else{
            if($pass!=null) {
                $pass = Hash::make(request('password'));
            }
            $user1 = new users();
            $user1->email =$em;
            $user1->password=$pass;
            $user1->firstName=$firstName;
            $user1->lastName=$lastName;
            $user1->save();
            /*$data = array("email" => $em, "password" => $pass, "firstName" => $firstName, "lastName" => $lastName);
            DB::table('users')->insert($data);*/
        }



        return redirect('/');
    }


    public function usession(Request $request){
      dd($request->session()->all());
    }
}
```

**The login Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated()
    {
        // Update last_session after logged-in
        User::find(Auth::id())->update(['laravel_session'=>Session::getId()]);
    }

}
```

[**result of:  php artisan route:list**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqEGD.png)

Comment: Your routes never call the LoginController, why did you post it? Laravel 5.7 ships with a complete Auth system, I think this is a custom one, right?

Comment: please show us this command result
php artisan route:list

Comment: @DitoKhelaia i just updated the post with the results you asked for

Comment: @dparoli im new to this sorry , do you have any references that may help me using the laravel auth system ?! besides the laravel documentation.

Comment: Try changing `$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');` to this `$this->middleware('auth');` in you're PagesController __construct method

Comment: Please @Mukashi dont stress yourself reinventing the Laravel Auth system, it's one of the best you can find and it's really a hard work doing one from scratch. The documentation, readed carefully with the source, it's more than enough: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Comment: @dparoli yeah i know i'm not doing that intentionally, i'm just newbie in laravel, thanks for your help but i already read the documentation but didn't help that much, is their any other resource you know ?!

Comment: @ViperTecPro didn't work

Comment: Use a good editor that helps you to find class and function definitions and dig the source code, best time spent as a developer to learn laravel and php.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your routes file, for your login routes you are calling the **login** and **validateLogin** functions on the **PagesController**, and in your PagesController in the **construct** function you have a middleware protecting the functions on this controller, with is the guest middleware.
To calirfy this to you, the middleware here it is like saying that all the functions existing on this controller are only seen by guests, and that is why when you log in, and navigate to other routes that are calling functions on PagesController, the midleware will prevent you, because these routes are only for guests (users who are not logged In)
so to solve this, you cn try one of these solutions:

- In the construct method in the PagesController, change it to

`$this->middleware('guest', ['only' => [ 'login', 'validateLogin' ]]);`

- Or move the login and validateLogin to LoginController so you can set the middleware to guest them. (And this is the best solution, to organize your code)

Comment: thanks for your help, I did exactly what you said and i got error when i run the application : https://imgur.com/tMgnSk0

Comment: can you show me the error? And I have edited my answer, you can try one of these solutions that I`ve listed, sorry about not clarifying that.

Comment: (1)-for the first solution i got this error after applying it: 
[link](https://i.imgur.com/tMgnSk0.png)

(2)-for the second solution the website works but when i try to visit the login page i get this eror:
[link](https://i.imgur.com/G6zSfH1.png)

Comment: 1-  For the first solution change it to this `$this->middleware('guest', ['only' => [ 'login', 'validateLogin' ]]);` there is a typo mistake